# Rewrite all files from folder to another folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I want redirect all requested files from folder-a to folder-b. E.g. http://www.yoursite.com/folder-a/index.php to http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/index.php.

How can I do that? I have verified if mod_rewrite works with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^google.html$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301]
```

The structure on the webspace is the following:

.htacces
|-folder-a
|-folder-b

But if I want my folder redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/folder-a/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the redirect doesn't work if I input the following URL:

http://www.yoursite.com/folder-a/
http://www.yoursite.com/folder-a/index.php

The redirect doesn't take place. I stay on the same page ... What I'm doing wrong? I also tried it with this htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder-a(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

If all this works I want to exclude some files. Eg. with this htaccess:

```
RedirectPermanent /folder-a/info.php /folder-b/new-info.php
```

**Edit**:

Now I tried this htaccess

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/folder-a/ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b
```

This works, but I need something which takes the whole path and rewrite it to the new folder.

This for example doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^folder-a/(.*)$ folder-b/$1
```

**Solution**

I had an old htacess file in my `folder-a` so the redirect didn't worked. This is my final htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder-a/excludefile1.php http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/newnameforfile1.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder-a/excludefile2.php http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/newnameforfile2.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder-a/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to put both rules in place: one for the empty folder and one for other files, and then the catch-all at the bottom.  This is not tested:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder-a/info.php http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/new-info.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder-a/ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^folder-a/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but it didn't worked. I don't know why. I set up two test folder and put a file into it. In my htaccess I had the following `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/test2/$1 [L,R=301]`. This redirect worked. If I adapt it to my real folder it stops working...

Comment: I found the error. I had an old .htaccess in my folder-a. This stoped the redirect working. I thought I had deleted it ... BTW: I deleted this rule `RewriteRule ^folder-a/ http://www.yoursite.com/folder-b/ [L,R=301]` because I than got redirected to folder-b/index.php.